# IE8 does not get right image width with jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I got an simple html/jquery slideshow works perfect in all major browsers but not in IE8

The images in question have an inline width and height and the flowing css:
`img{border-style: none;width: auto;height: auto;padding:0;margin:0;}`

Using jquery i am trying to get the img width using:

```
this.img_list = $('.sponsoren_img');
this.theWidth = this.img_list.width();
```

The function that holds this action is trigger wihtin `$().ready(function() {...});`

In IE9,FF en chrome it gets the right width of the image which is 140. Ie8 thinks its 136

Whats going on here?

For those who want to see the slideshow in action, visit: [www.elementalworks.nl/KPJOD](http://www.elementalworks.nl/KPJOD)
It is the box next to the Welkom box.

Comment: Is the width set in a width attribute, or the style attribute.

Comment: you need to make sure that this function is being fired after the images have finished loading otherwise the width will be wrong - your code seems to work fine in ie8 with placeholder images: http://jsfiddle.net/vpCtr/1/

Comment: The width is set as an attribute not inline css. An extra load function also did not did the trick. If the image wasn't loaded wouldnt it return 0?